# unable to display elements of same width and height correctly with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm a beginner in html and css and I have created a flexbox container where I want an image and a description as two div elements to cover my whole screen width with equal width and height and then go a row down and do the same for the next image and description .
The picture below represents the display I am trying to make perfectly :
[image]

As seen in the picture above the image and description are of same width and height something that I cannot do perfectly using my code below  with flexbox :

```html
 <div class="services-container">
        <div><img src = "IMAGES/flexwing.png"></div> 
        <div><h1>Commited to the highest international standards</h1><br/>
             <div class = "line">
             <p>Our clients trust as and love us . We are the best airline force . <br/> Salute !</p> 
             </div>        
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Play our game to get a discount ticket <br/> for a flight to the Dodecanese !</h1>
          <button class = "play-btn">Play here</button>
        </div>
        <div><img src = "IMAGES/dodecanese.jpg"></div>
    </div>
```

```css
.services-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    position: relative;
    bottom:32px;
    width:100%;
}

.services-container div{
    margin:0;
    width:50%;
    background-color: white;
    height:auto;
}

.services-container h1 {
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
}

.line{
    border-top:1px solid rgb(217, 0, 217);
    width:10%;
    
}

.services-container p{
    font-size:30px;
    text-align: center;
}


.play-btn{
    border-radius:2px ;
    color:green;
}
```

I have added `width:50%` for each element so that each one covers half page width so I can have 2 elements on each row but after my first 2 elements I have assymetry in all my elements like below :

[image]

[image]

I would appreciate your help with this . Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intrinsic widths of your images are smaller than their containing blocks. Add the following declarations to your image selector:

```css
img {
  width: 100%; /* ensure width is equal to containing block's content area */
  display: block; /* remove any white-space */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your second row picture have less width than the picture in the first row. And you can't change the width of picture by applying `width:x% or xpx` to the `div` containing the image. But you can achieve that by giving a width to this`<img src = "IMAGES/dodecanese.jpg">` and the first image. Give the same width.
e.g:`<img src = "IMAGES/dodecanese.jpg" width=500px>`

Comment: I did but the result is the same

Comment: okay, try putting those 2 sections inside two different `div` and then do `display:flex` on each of the `divs`. I can't really say because your image isn't visible, on running the code I can't see any image because the images are stored in your pc

Comment: Dude I figured out your mistake, damn, you are a total newbie. Need a lot of work. First of all your divs are all messed up

Comment: What was it  then ?Could you provide an example ?